# Adding the key in the first state of keyed sponge-based hash function

Tags: hash, cryptanalysis, sponge

What are the advantages to add the key in the inner or outer part of first state in keyed sponge hash functions?

Comment: This question hasn't received any answer for quite a long time and has been flagged as being unclear what is asked. If you still want this question answered, please expand your answer and e.g. give an example or point to a paper where the inner / outer part are defined.